# R - Filter dataframe to only included rows where the column count meets a criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

Assume this dataframe:

```
country <- c('USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'Canada')
number <- c(1:9)
df <- data.frame(country, number)
```

I want to be able to subset only the rows where the country count is greater than 4 or less than 2. So in this case, it would return:

```
country  number
USA      1
USA      2
USA      3
USA      4
USA      5
Canada   9
```

I am able to make it work with this:

```
totalcounts <- filter(count(df, country), n>4 | n<2) # giving me a df of the country and count
for (i in nrow(totalcounts)){
  # code in here that rbinds rows as it matches
}
```

But I feel there has to be an easier way. I haven't gotten the grasp of sapply and such yet, so I feel like I'm missing something here. It just seems like I am going the long way around and there is already something in place that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a group by filter

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(country) %>% 
   filter(n() > 4|n() < 2)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   country [2]
#  country number
#  <chr>    <int>
#1 USA          1
#2 USA          2
#3 USA          3
#4 USA          4
#5 USA          5
#6 Canada       9
```

---

Or another option is to create a column of counts with `add_count` and `filter`

```
df %>%
    add_count(country) %>% 
    filter(n > 4|n < 2) %>% 
    select(-n)
```

---

Or do a join if we use the `count`

```
df %>%
    count(country) %>% 
    filter(n >4 |n <2) %>% 
    select(country) %>% 
    inner_join(df)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(df,!ave(number,country,FUN = function(x) length(x)%in% c(2:4)))
```

or a shorter version (Thank @Onyambu)

```
subset(df,!ave(number,country,FUN = length) %in% 2:4)
```

such that

```
  country number
1     USA      1
2     USA      2
3     USA      3
4     USA      4
5     USA      5
9  Canada      9
```

Comment: You know you could shorten this `subset(df,!ave(number,country,FUN = length) %in% 2:4)`

Answer (score 3):

Base R option using `table` :

```
tab <- table(df$country)
subset(df, country %in% names(tab[tab > 4 | tab < 2]))

#  country number
#1     USA      1
#2     USA      2
#3     USA      3
#4     USA      4
#5     USA      5
#9  Canada      9
```